# Java Servlets cant use session attribute in another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get my first servlets to work. I have found some similar problems and solutions to them, but it´s not excatly what I would like to do.

This is my login servlet:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        if(LoginValidator.validate(username, password)){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", username);
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
            Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("sessionKuki", username);
            sessionCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
            response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("paste.jsp"); //INSTEAD of paste.jsp I would like to get session attribute called uri I set in filter. BUT I when I try to use get attribute, Eclipse says there is no attribute called URI. 
            rd.forward(request,response);  
        }
        else{  
            out.print("Sorry username or password error");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
            rd.include(request,response);
        }

        out.close(); 
    }
}
```

And there is filter that I use to redirect to login page, when user is not signed in:

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter{

//  private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //this.context = filterConfig.getServletContext();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI(); //THERE IS uri of the site from where the user    gets redirected to login page

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("uri", uri); // HERE I TRY to set uri to session attribute. My intention is to use that uri in my login servlet


        if(uri.endsWith(".css")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if(uri.endsWith(".js")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }


        if(session == null && !(uri.endsWith("login.html") || uri.endsWith("login") || uri.endsWith("forgot.jsp") || uri.endsWith("signup.jsp"))){
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
            System.out.print("redirecting to login");
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }


    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Is it even possible, what I am trying to do? How to do it? Is there a better way to do it? I dont want to mix html and script. My intention is that, when user comes to a pages, and trys to get access to somewhere, he is redirected to login page. And after he logs in, he should be redirected to the page he wanted to go at the beginning.

Comment: Looks like you want to move `session.setAttribute("uri", uri);` after validating `.css`, `.js` or any other resource GET request.

Comment: if you use `false` in `req.getSession(false);` make sure to handle the `null` case or else someone who has no session and access the page will trigger NPE.

Comment: to Luiggi: excuse me I am total beginner, so it can be done? but I have to use session.setAttribute("uri",uri) somewhere else?              to Andrei: thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but please try doing your filter like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();

        HttpSession currentSession = req.getSession(false);


        if(uri.endsWith(".css")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if(uri.endsWith(".js")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }


        if(currentSession == null && !(uri.endsWith("login.html") || uri.endsWith("login") || uri.endsWith("forgot.jsp") || uri.endsWith("signup.jsp"))){
            HttpSession newSession = req.getSession();
            newSession.setAttribute("uri", uri);
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
            System.out.print("redirecting to login");
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

What i did was create a new session in the filter if the `session` is null.

Comment: By syntax it is correct now. But when I get the uri in loginservlet, the value of uri is "null" when I print it out. I am trying to find the reason, but havent found yet.

Comment: So have you tried the filter I posted ? Are you sure the value is not `null` when you set it ?

Comment: Yes, I tried your filter and it was null. I think I am using wrong method in loginservlet, because in filter even after setting it gives the right uri. But in loginservlet it is "null". I am using in loginservlet: String uri=request.getParameter("uri"); is it wrong?

Comment: Erm...why get it from the request when you set it on the session ? Try this:  `session.getAttribute("uri");`

Comment: tried that first, also newSession.getAt...  and SessionFilter.session.getAttribute("uri"); but eclipse says session cant be resolved

Comment: Try adding `request.getSession(false);` in the servlet and see if it is `null` or not.

Comment: Yes, it is still null.

Comment: For example, this gives also null in the filter:  newSession.setAttribute("uri", uri);
            String uri2=request.getParameter("uri");
            System.out.println(uri2);         So I agree that I should use session.getAttribute("uri") but I really cant figure out why eclipse does not allow it.

Comment: In the previous comment I meant to see if `request.getSession(false);` returns `null` or not, not the `getAttribute`.